# Parsing nested json with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, nested-json

I have some JSON.

```
{
  ZVH2: {
    username: 'ZVH2',
    ping: 0,
    uuid: '3a4423c3-dce1-40c1-8333-ab2ffdfcd005',
    displayName: ChatMessage {
      json: [Object],
      text: '',
      extra: [Array],
      bold: undefined,
      italic: undefined,
      underlined: undefined,
      strikethrough: undefined,
      obfuscated: undefined,
      color: undefined
    },
    entity: Entity {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      id: 367,
      type: 'player',
      position: [Vec3],
      velocity: [Vec3],
      yaw: 3.141592653589793,
      pitch: 0,
      onGround: false,
      height: 1.62,
      width: 0,
      effects: [Object],
      equipment: [Array],
      heldItem: [Item],
      isValid: true,
      metadata: [Array],
      username: 'ZVH2',
      name: 'player',
      timeSinceOnGround: 0,
      attributes: [Object],
      isInWater: false,
      isInLava: false,
      isInWeb: undefined,
      isCollidedHorizontally: false,
      isCollidedVertically: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    gamemode: 2
  },
  Maximo237354: {
    username: 'Maximo237354',
    ping: 161,
    uuid: 'd6d1bcda-d3c0-406b-b91e-beb3f7be9f5f',
    displayName: ChatMessage {
      json: [Object],
      text: '',
      extra: [Array],
      bold: undefined,
      italic: undefined,
      underlined: undefined,
      strikethrough: undefined,
      obfuscated: undefined,
      color: undefined
    },
    entity: Entity {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      id: 72,
      type: 'player',
      position: [Vec3],
      velocity: [Vec3],
      yaw: 2.773437264497239,
      pitch: -0.04908738521234035,
      onGround: true,
      height: 1.62,
      width: 0.6,
      effects: [Object],
      equipment: [Array],
      heldItem: [Item],
      isValid: true,
      metadata: [Array],
      name: 'player',
      username: 'Maximo237354',
      uuid: 'd6d1bcda-d3c0-406b-b91e-beb3f7be9f5f',
      dataBlobs: undefined,
      attributes: [Object],
      headYaw: 2.773437264497239,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use javascript to print the username of username in here. It can either iterate through each thing and print the username value, or it can just take the first value because that is the username too. I can't find a good tutorial online anywhere for this. I want to make sure that I print every username and not entity. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: If what's you need is to extract object's keys, try `Object.keys(yourDataset)` See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: _"I have some JSON"_... no, you don't. That's a JavaScript object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your JSON variable is called `data`, you can extract the keys with `Object.keys(data)`

To iterate and get the usernames you can do

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
   let username = data[key].username;
});
```

Comment: The keys are already the usernames

Comment: I'm wondering why you wouldn't simply convert this back into a JavaScript object and then get it that way rather than  parsing a string.  That's the whole purpose of JSON is that it represents a JavaScript Object.